# How to add the proper type annotations when converting an integer to a float?

Tags: rust

What's the proper type annotation in the following code to convert an integer to a float?

```
use conv::{ValueInto, errors::PosOverflow};
                                  
fn run_me() -> Result <f32, PosOverflow<usize>> {                                 
    let m: f32 = 21.3;                                                          
    let n: usize = 23;                                                          
    let p: f32 = n.value_into()?;                                               
    let bar = m * p;                                                             
    let baz = m * (n.value_into()?);  // Compiler error here                                           
    Ok(baz)                                                             
}
                                                                       
fn main() {                                                                      
    run_me();                                                                     
}
```

Which fails with:

```
error[E0277]: cannot multiply `()` to `f32`
 --> src/main.rs:7:17
  |
7 |     let baz = m * (n.value_into()?);
  |                 ^ no implementation for `f32 * ()`
  |
  = help: the trait `std::ops::Mul<()>` is not implemented for `f32`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `(): conv::ValueFrom<usize>` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:7:22
  |
7 |     let baz = m * (n.value_into()?);
  |                      ^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `conv::ValueFrom<usize>` is not implemented for `()`
  |
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `conv::ValueInto<()>` for `usize`

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: Could not compile `tmp3`.

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

Basically, a conversion from `usize` to `f32` could fail, so we have the `conv` package to handle the details.  In the following code, the `bar` computes just fine, but `baz` does not.  I'd like a one liner like `baz` to work directly because more complicated examples will need to chain together multiple conversions.

---

## Edit 1

Ok, so I can force what I want by adding a trait to `usize`.  Is there a problem with this approach or can the original call to `value_into` be fixed?

```
use conv::{ValueFrom, ValueInto, errors::PosOverflow};

trait ToF32 {
    fn to_f32(self) -> Result<f32, PosOverflow<usize>>;
}

impl ToF32 for usize {
    fn to_f32(self) -> Result<f32, PosOverflow<usize>> {                    
        f32::value_from(self)   
    }
}

fn run_me() -> Result <f32, PosOverflow<usize>> {
    let m: f32 = 21.3;
    let n: usize = 23;
    let p: f32 = n.value_into()?;
    let bar = m * p;
    let baz = m * n.to_f32()?;            
    // let buz = m * n.value_into()?;
    Ok(baz)
}

fn main() {
    run_me();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some functions in Rust like `value_into` and `try_into` have to be called when assigning to directly to a typed variable.

To answer your question directly, the proper way to add type annotations is by assigning it into a temporary variable (like you did with `bar` and `p`) before using the value.